# simple css image switch with opacity rollover

Tags: html, css, jscript

Please see the following code pen:
http://codepen.io/kishoresahas/pen/epbjRm

```
function switchImg(i) {
  document.getElementById("imageSRC").src = i;
}
```

As you can see the function swaps the larger image depending on the thumbnail you select. At the moment if you hover over either thumbnail, the opacity changes as follows:

```
.button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the selected thumbnail instead receives and stays in the 'opacity hover state' - to indicate its larger counterpart is now being shown and visa versa. So I don't want a hover state, I want a 'selected' opacity effect.

Comment: Do you mean the selected thumbnail should have `opacity: 1` or should have `opacity: 0.8` ?

Comment: The selected thumbnail should get the opacity, ie 0.8 and it stays in that state if you roll-off

Answer (score 0):

Set also `opacity: 0.8` on the id `imageSRC`

```
#imageSRC,
.button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjqYJG)

**Update**

If you're not using Jquery use this:

**HTML**

```
  <img id="imageSRC" src="http://bonrouge.com/wine.jpg" id="wine" height="500" width="300" alt="">

  <a href="#" onClick="switchImg('http://bonrouge.com/wine.jpg', this)" class="button">
    <img src="http://bonrouge.com/wine.jpg" height="100" width="100" alt="">
  </a>

  <a href="#" onClick="switchImg('http://bonrouge.com/beer.jpg', this)" class="button">
    <img src="http://bonrouge.com/beer.jpg" height="100" width="100" alt="">
  </a>
```

**JS**

```
function switchImg(i, self) {
  document.getElementById("imageSRC").src = i;
  removeSelectedThumbnail();
  self.classList.add("selectedThumbnail");
}

function removeSelectedThumbnail() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll("a.button");
  [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    el.className = el.className.replace(/\bselectedThumbnail\b/, "");
  });
}
```

**CSS**

```
.button:hover,
.selectedThumbnail {
  opacity: 0.8
}
```

So on every switch, we add a class name `selectedThumbnail` to the selected thumbnail and define it's opacity for that specific class in the css.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oafo4ouw/5/)

**Update**:
To have the selected thumbnail have the opacity when the page loads, add `selectedThumbnail` class to the selected one.

e.g.

```
<a href="#" onClick="switchImg('http://bonrouge.com/wine.jpg', this)" class="button selectedThumbnail">
  <img src="http://bonrouge.com/wine.jpg" height="100" width="100" alt="">
</a>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oafo4ouw/6/)

Comment: The opacity should be on the selected thumbnail

Comment: Yeah that code above should do the job. Or should the unselected thumbnail won't have the opacity regardless if it's on hover state or not?

Comment: The way you did it, you make the big image get the opacity. I want the big image to be opacity:1. The opacity is just to go on the small image/thumbnail - to show the user which big image is being shown...so if I select the small image on the right by clicking it, the small image gets the opacity .8 and the big image changes to the one selected. The small image stays in the opacity state - unless you select the small image on left - then that one would show big and the small left thumbnail would now have the opacity.

Comment: That's much better, and the effect I was looking for - there is just one thing: I need the thumbnail of the big selected image to already have the opacity when the page loads, (as it is already selected).

Comment: @RobertSheppard Great! Glad it helped.